# Bin? Not Showing Up In Cygwin Installation Select Packages

Tags: windows-10, installation, cygwin

I am following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html) for setting up cLion with cygwin. In the guide, the second step is to add these pacakges:

```
gcc-g++
make
gdb
```

and select the `bin?` tick mark. However, in my installation page, it doesn't show that.[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get the `bin?` selection, or if it isn't there in the latest update, how do I select it? I'm on Windows 10 currently

Answer (score 0):

That's ironic... I spent an hour of research on this, and 10 minutes after posting this, I fixed it.

You don't need to use `bin?`. In the section to the left of `source?` you will see `new`. If the package you want has `keep` in that section, it's already adding it. If it has `skip`, then it will skip that package in installation, so you have to double-click on `skip`. You will then see a version number, like 9.2.1 (just an example), which means that it will add that package.